# How can I control the order my jQuery plugin iterates with .each()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I created a plugin that clones elements for rapid prototyping.  The plugin will iterate through each element that has a data-attribute of 'data-clone' on the element, and clone amount set in the attribute.

example:

```
<table data-clone="3">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Project</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-clone="4">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Steve Sax</td>
            <td>Something here.</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This seems to work well on the first element.  However, if i have a nested item where the container is cloned and so are elements inside.  It seems it clones the nested items, and the outer on the first, but will not clone those nested items into the newly cloned outer containers.

I have a fiddle here: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adamin/u46Ps/3/)

It has the plugin and the call.  If you click 'Run' you should see exactly what I mean.

However, I feel if the .each() method iterated from the nested item first, then worked its way up, all clones would be correct.

Thanks in advance,

Adam.

Here is the plugin itself for reference.  Again, all is in the fiddle as well.

```
/*! Adamin Clone - v0.1.0 - 2012-09-29
  * https://github.com/pensive612/Adamin-Clone
  * Copyright (c) 2012 Adam L.; Licensed MIT, GPL */

(function(window, document, $, undefined) {
    var Project = function(elem, options) {
      this.elem = elem;
      this.$elem = $(elem);
      this.options = options;
      this.metadata = this.$elem.data('clone-cap');
};

Project.prototype = {
  defaults: {
    cloneCap: 100
  },
  init: function() {
    this.config = $.extend({}, this.defaults, this.options, this.metadata);

    this.getCloneValue(this.$elem);

    return this;
  },
  getCloneValue: function(elem) {
    var configCap = this.config.cloneCap;
    var cloneValue = elem.data('clone');

    // parse data-clone value
    cloneValue = this.parseCloneValue(cloneValue);

    // if data-clone value is valid, send to clone function
    if ( cloneValue && (cloneValue < configCap) ) {
      this.cloneItem(this.$elem, cloneValue);

    // otherwise, return false
    } else {

      if (cloneValue > configCap) {
        window.console.log('Your data-clone value is too high for the defaults.  Please check documentation to override cap in config.');
      }

      return false;
    }
  },
  parseCloneValue: function(value) {
    var cloneValue = parseInt(value, 10);
    return cloneValue;
  },
  cloneItem: function(elem, value) {
    var elemClone;

    for (var i = value; i > 0; i--) {
      elemClone = elem.clone(true);
      elemClone.removeAttr('data-clone');
      elemClone.addClass('clone-' + i);
      elemClone.insertAfter(elem);
    }
  }
};

Project.defaults = Project.prototype.defaults;

$.fn.adaminClone = function(options, callback) {

  if (typeof callback === 'function') {
    callback.call(this);
  }

  return this.each(function() {
    new Project(this, options).init();
  });
};

window.Project = Project;

}(window, document, jQuery));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ComputerArts did an awesome job of rewriting the function.  However, I was able to maintain the plugin pattern and extendibility by only modifying:

```
return this.each(function() {
  new Project(this, options).init();
});
```

To this:

```
  return this.sort(function(a, b) {
    var va = $(a).parents('[data-clone]').length;
    var vb = $(b).parents('[data-clone]').length;
    return vb - va;
  }).each(function() {
      new Project(this, options).init();
  });
```

Using parents().length is a great way to measure depth.  Thanks to ComputerArts and Shoky for getting me where I needed to be on it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I got something for you.

[Check this simplified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u46Ps/11/)

Basically you start cloning from the deepest element and go upward.
Comments are in the code.

```
var elements = $.find('[data-clone]'); //get all the elements that need to be cloned
var elementsData = []; //will store and sort the elements

//store the elements with their depth
$.each(elements, function(i, element) {

    var obj = {};
    obj.element = $(element);
    obj.depth = $(element).parents().length;

    elementsData.push(obj);

    // This can be optimized, it's just easier to understand the code.
    // Alternatively use 
    // elementsData.push({ element : $(element), depth : $(element).parents().length }); 
})

//sort them by deepest element
elementsData.sort(SortByDepth);


$.each(elementsData, function(i, elementData) {
    var element = elementData.element;

    //clone ot the number of times wanted.
    for (var c = 0; c < element.attr('data-clone'); c++) {
        element
            .clone(true)
            .removeAttr('data-clone')
            .addClass('clone-' + c).
            insertAfter(element);
    }
})

//function that sorts the elements;
function SortByDepth(a, b){
  var aDepth = a.depth;
  var bDepth = b.depth;
  return ((aDepth > bDepth) ? -1 : ((aDepth < bDepth) ? 1 : 0));
}
```

NOTE: in the data-clone=4, the script will clone it 4 times, so you'll have a total of 5 on screen (because of the one already there). It you want exactly 4, in the for loop jut put

```
for (var c = 0; c < parseInt(element.attr('data-clone') - 1); c++) {
```

Comment: Wow, ComputerArts.  Thank you so much for the time you put into this.  I completely see where you were going with it.  i did something similar (with the help of a shoky) which retains its plugin pattern, and still gets the job done pretty quickly.

Comment: You're welcome. I went really line by line and really simple in order to make it understandable for even a new user of JavaScript. I told myself that you seemed to know js so you'd be able to optimize it.